# Why Error ? Syntax Rand Function

Tags: php, random

Why Error ?

> Warning: mt_rand() [function.mt-rand]: max(0) is smaller than min(1) in /users/avsm/www/pa-include/functions.php on line 332

Here function.php line 332

```
$rand = mt_rand(1,$count);
```

from line 332 to 346

```
db_close();

$count = count($img);

$rand = mt_rand(1,$count);

db_connect();
  $query = "SELECT * FROM pa_videos WHERE id = $rand";
  $result = @mysql_query($query);

  while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $imag = $row['img'];
    $title = $row['title'];
  }
db_close();

if(!$imag) {
  $rand = mt_rand(1,$count);
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: max(0) is smaller than min(1) . Thats the reason

Comment: Your problem is in the `$count` variable.

Comment: my problem is line 332 , $rand = mt_rand(1,$count);

Comment: No, your problem is using functions without having gone through its documentation/manual

Answer (score 1):

`mt_rand` accepts two arguments - the range's minimum and maximum, in that order. Naturally, the maximum must be larger than the minimum. Your minimum is hardcoded to be `1`, and your maximum is `$counter`, which seems to have the value of `0` in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$count` is less than 1 that's why it's shows error. here the syntax of rand function so its helpful to you.

```
int mt_rand ( int $min , int $max )

//example: echo mt_rand(5, 15);
```